# How to correctly pass variables to and from non-default constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I am writing a program for homework assignment in C++. I am having bit of a problem with passing values from one initialized constructor to the other and it says:

```
error C2664: 'Book::Book(std::string,Author *,Publisher *,double)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'Author' to 'Author *'
```

I'm a bit rusty in OOP and new to C++.

Please post if I should include more code I will attach code from main class and class from which I cant do the conversion. The program isn't nearly finished.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Book.h"

void main()
{
    cout << "Book 1" << endl;

    Author *pAuthor = new Author("John", "Doe");
    Publisher *pPublisher = new Publisher("Wrox", "10475 Crosspoint Blvd.", "Indianapolis");
    Book *book = new Book("Memory Management", *pAuthor, *pPublisher, 49.99);

    cout << "Book 2" << endl;
    int i;
    cin >> i;
};
```

Comment: A few points: you shouldn't be using `new` at all, and you already have memory leaks in this simple program because of it. Taking the address of a temporary is illegal `&(ostringstream() << number)` and shouldn't compile. Also, `string(title)` is redundant, it can just be `title`. Also `void main` is illegal, it should be `int main` and you don't have to return anything from it and it will automatically return `0` (although _no other function_ will do this, `main` is a special case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't dereference the Author and Publisher pointers, since the Book constructor expects pointers, not values passed in.

However, when dealing with all those pointers, you could have lots of memory management problems. This would be OK for a small program since all memory is released once the program exits, however getting into the habit of managing your memory correctly is important. If you want to avoid passing by value, maybe you should read about references in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Book's constructor wants pointers but you give it dereferenced values.

```
                                   wants pointer       wants pointer
                                    ^                  ^                                        
                                    |                  |
                                    |                  |
Book::Book(string title, Author *pAuthor, Publisher *pPublisher, double price)
{
    title = title;
    price = price;
}
```

But in the main(),

```
Book *book = new Book("Memory Management", *pAuthor, *pPublisher, 49.99);
                                             |          |
                                             |          |
                                            \/         \/
                                        Dereferenced, so its a value copied
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are just setting values you should probably be receiving the parameters as const references:

```
Author::Author(const string& first, const string& last)
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
}
```

Then just pass them in the normal way:

```
Author *pAuthor = new Author("John", "Doe");
```

Or if you are only using the author object within that method, you don't really need to be using `new` you can just put it on the stack, this would avoid potential memory leaks in your program:

```
Author author("John", "Doe");
```